# Formatting Double in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, string-formatting

I want to to format a double values like `###,###.00` and I'm trying the following code:

```
double num = 0.00;
Console.WriteLine("Value with two decimal places: " + 
                      "{0:###,###.00}", num);
```

It works fine for all values except `0` or `0.00` etc. for `0` it outputs `.00` whereas I want it to emit `0.00`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then you should use this:

```
double num = 0.00;
Console.WriteLine("Value with two decimal places: " + 
                      "{0:###,##0.00}", num);
```

`0` means: Always print a digit at this place, whether it exits or not. Prints 0 if it doesn't exist.
`#` means: Only print a digit at this place, if it really exists.